# Sort a string alphabetically using a function

Tags: javascript, sorting

Imagine you were given a string and you had to sort that string alphabetically using a function. Example:

```
sortAlphabets( 'drpoklj' ); //=> returns 'djklopr'
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I tried myself, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. This answer just adds to my experience.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use array [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function:

```
var sortAlphabets = function(text) {
    return text.split('').sort().join('');
};
```

**STEPS**

1. Convert `string` to `array`
2. Sort `array`
3. Convert back `array` to `string`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pwzjd846/1/)

Comment: What's the space and time complexity of this solution?

Comment: @kdizzle Each of these methods is O(N) on its own...

Comment: Time Complexity: sort is O(N logN), split and join is O(N), so time complexity is O(N logN). Space Complexity is O(N).

Answer (score 38):

Newer browsers support [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which makes sorting `utf8` encoded strings really simple. Note that different languages may have a different order of characters. More information on [MDN about localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
function sortAlphabet(str) {
  return [...str].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
}

console.log(sortAlphabet("drpoklj")); // Logs: "djklopr"
```

If you only have to support ascii strings then the default sorting implementation will do.

```js
function sortAlphabet(str) {
  return [...str].sort().join("");
}
```

Comment: Note that the returned value is an array while it should be a string, so need to add `.join("")`

Comment: @yl2015 Good catch! I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 21):

As previous answers have shown, you convert the string to an array of single-character strings, sort that, and then recombine it into a string. **But**, using `split` isn't the best practice way to do that first step, because a JavaScript string is a series of UTF-16 code units with invalid surrogate pairs tolerated, and `split("")` splits up surrogate pairs into their individual code units, potentially separating them, thus breaking the code *point* (loosely: character) they're supposed to form as a pair. So if you have an emoji in the string (for instance) or any of hundreds of thousands of characters in non-Western scripts, those can get broken.

In ES5 and earlier, correctly splitting the string required that you detect and handle surrogate pairs to ensure they stayed together, which was a bit of a pain and involved checking `charCodeAt` for specific ranges of values.

As of ES2015+, it's really easy: You just use the string's iterator, which is defined to provide each code *point* in the string, whether that's a single code unit or two. To get an array of the code points, you can use the iterator via spread notation (`[...str]`) or `Array.from` (`Array.from(str)`).

So using that, we get:

```
function sortAlphabets(str) {
    return [...str].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// Using the iterator
function sortAlphabets(str) {
    return [...str].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
}

// Using split("")
function sortAlphabetsUsingSplit(str) {
    return str.split("").sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
}

const str = "देवनागरी";
console.log("Original string    : " + str);
console.log("Using the iterator : " + sortAlphabets(str));
console.log("Using split('')    : " + sortAlphabetsUsingSplit(str));
```

Note how using `split`, some of the characters have gotten mangled.