# Sorting a string alphabetically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've some issues with a relativly simple task. I have to sort the characters of a string and return the sorted string (in Javascript). After googling for answers I figured out the solution but for some reason the methods doesn't return the output I expected.

```
var str = "Something";
var chars = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chars.push(str.charAt(i));
}

chars.sort().join("");
console.log(chars);
```

The output I receive is this:

```
["S", "e", "g", "h", "i", "m", "n", "o", "t"]
```

1.) Despite of using the .join() method the charachters are still comma-separated. Also tried to use the .replace() method but that brings me to the second issue.

2.) The typeof chars remains an object although .join() should return a string. I also tried using the .toString() method but the type of output still remains an object.

Comment: `chars.push()` pushes into an array, so a comma is expected - use `chars +=` instead

Comment: Note that by default `.sort()` doesn't sort alphabetically, it sorts according to each character's Unicode code point value. Which ends up as alphabetical if you have all lowercase or all uppercase letters, but in your case you don't. (So `"apple"` comes after `"Zebra"`, but before `"zebra"`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912663/sort-a-string-alphabetically-using-a-function

Answer (score 16):

`join()` does not modify the array, but returns a new object, which you currently not use. So your code should look like this:

```
var str = "Something";
var chars = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chars.push(str.charAt(i));
}

chars = chars.sort().join("");
console.log(chars);
```

You could, however, do this in a one liner:

```
let chars = str.split('').sort().join('');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const sorted = str.split('').sort().join('')
```