# arranging words in an alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I have a question, I have a text.file that contains a string, this code right now prints out words  and lets me know how many same words have been used..
Is there a way that I could put the words in an alphabetical order in the Node.js environment.

Code:

```
const { readFile, readFileSync } = require('fs');

let file = 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\source\\repos\\Nodejs\\pish\\pish\\TextFile2.txt';

let words = "";

function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
let words = sentence.split(" ");
let wordMap = {};

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let currentWordCount = wordMap[words[i]];
    let count = currentWordCount ? currentWordCount : 0;
    wordMap[words[i]] = count + 1;
}
return wordMap;
}

words = readFileSync(file).toString();
console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a string alphabetically using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912663/sort-a-string-alphabetically-using-a-function)

Comment: add a sample so we have something to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to create a list of your object entries, then sort them by key using `Array.sort()`, then create your sorted map using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

let file = 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\source\\repos\\Nodejs\\pish\\pish\\TextFile2.txt';

function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
    const wordMap = sentence.toLowerCase().split(" ").reduce((acc,cur) => { 
        acc[cur] = (acc[cur] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    // Sort the map alphabetically...
    const sortedEntries = Object.entries(wordMap).sort(([a,],[b,]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    const sortedWordMap = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries);
    return sortedWordMap;
}

const words = readFileSync(file).toString();
console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

And a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
        
function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
    const wordMap = sentence.toLowerCase().split(" ").reduce((acc,cur) => {
        acc[cur] = (acc[cur] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    // Sort the map alphabetically...
    const sortedEntries = Object.entries(wordMap).sort(([a,],[b,]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    const sortedWordMap = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries);
    return sortedWordMap;
}

const words = `What a piece of work is a man How Noble in reason How infinite in faculty In form and moving how express and admirable In Action how like an Angel in apprehension how like a God The beauty of the world the paragon of animals and yet to me what is this quintessence of dust Man delights not me nor woman neither though by your smiling you seem to say so` ;
console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your data is wordMap = [{'word':'A'},{'word':'B'}, ...]

> ```
> wordMap.sort((a,b) => a.word - b.word);
> ```

2. Your data is wordMap = [A', 'B', ...]

> ```
> wordMap.sort();
> ```